# MySQL - Select rows from multiple tables based on the tables' names

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to set up a simple database via MySQL.
To sum up, I have a first Table 'A' containing a column 'name' and a column 'value'. Next I have a bunch of other tables 'name1', 'name2'... 'nameN' whose name actually correspond to one of the name stored in A.name.

Now I would want to select stuff from those tables based on a desired value for A.value. Something like that :

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT name from A WHERE A.value = desired_value );
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: This sounds like a poor database design.

Comment: Well I'm quite new to this, any suggestions maybe ?